# syntax of function Explicit specialization

Tags: c++

Based on the [tutorial](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) ，

```
// Example 2: Explicit specialization 
// 
template<class T> // (a) a base template 
void f( T ){;}

template<class T> // (b) a second base template, overloads (a) 
void f( T* ){;}     //     (function templates can't be partially 
//     specialized; they overload instead)

template<>        // (c) explicit specialization of (b) 
void f<>(int*){;} // ===> Method one
```

I also test the following with VS2010 SP1 without any warning.

```
template<>        // (c) alternative
void f<int>(int*){;} // ==> Method two
```

**Question**> Which way is recommended way based on the C++　standard? Method one or Method two?

As you can see the key different between Method one and Method two is as follows:

```
template<>        
void f<>(int*){;}    // ===> Method one

template<>        
void f<int>(int*){;} // ===> Method two
       ^^^
```

Based on the tutorial, we should write the following plain old function instead:

```
void f(int*){;}
```

But that is NOT the question I am asking:)

Thank you

Comment: Method one as `template<> void f<>(int *)` vs method two as `template<> void f<int>(int *)`?

Comment: I have updated my question again.

Answer (score 1):

> The full specialization declaration can omit explicit template
>   arguments when template being specialized can be determined via
>   argument deduction (using as argument types the parameter types
>   provided in the declaration) and partial ordering.[from "C++
>   Templates" by Vandervoode, Josuttis]

This it the case in your example so you can write:

```
template<>
void f(int){;}
```

to specialize (a) and

```
template<>
void f(int*){;}
```

to specialize (b).